# Lightning Component on Event Object, error message whily typing on input fields

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have overriden "New Event" standard action with a custom lightning component but i get an error while typing. Code below:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:availableForFlowScreens,lightning:actionOverride"
                controller="PoCEventsManagement"
                access="global">

    <!-- Event Handlers -->
    <aura:handler value="{!this}" name="init" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <!--Define Attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="eventRecord" type="Event" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="isActionClicked" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="spinner" type="boolean" default="true"/>

    <!-- If action is selected, show a modal!-->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isActionClicked}">
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_small">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <!--loading spinner start-->
                <div class="slds-is-relative">
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.spinner}">
                        <div aura:id="spinnerId" class="slds-spinner_container">
                            <div class="slds-spinner--brand  slds-spinner slds-spinner--medium slds-is-relative" role="alert">
                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </aura:if>

                    <!--Loading spinner end--> 
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                              onclick="{! c.closeModal }"
                                              alternativeText="close"
                                              variant="bare-inverse"
                                              class="slds-modal__close"/>
                        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_small slds-hyphenate">New Event</h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_small slds-wrap"  id="modal-content-id-1">
                        <!--26/03/2020 George Galaios: Subject-->
                        <lightning:input aura:id="evtSubject" name="evtSubject" label="Subject" value="{!v.eventRecord.Subject}" required="true" class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small" />

                        <!--26/03/2020 George Galaios: Assigned to-->
                        <lightning:input aura:id="evtAssignedTo" name="evtAssignedTo" label="OwnerId" value="{!v.eventRecord.OwnerId}" required="true" class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small" />

                        <!--26/03/2020 George Galaios: Start Datetime-->
                        <lightning:input aura:id="evtStart" type="Datetime" name="evtStart" label="Start" value="{!v.eventRecord.StartDateTime}" year="2-digit" month="short" day="2-digit" hour="numeric"
                                         weekday="long" minute="2-digit" class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small" />

                        <!--26/03/2020 George Galaios: End Datetime-->
                        <lightning:input aura:id="evtEnd" type="Datetime" name="evtEnd" label="End" value="{!v.eventRecord.EndDateTime}" year="2-digit" month="short" day="2-digit" hour="numeric"
                                         weekday="long" minute="2-digit" class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small" />

                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                            <div class="slds-p-top_medium"></div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <lightning:button iconName="utility:undo"
                                          iconPosition="right"
                                          variant="neutral" 
                                          label="Cancel Flow"
                                          title="Cancel Flow"
                                          onclick="{! c.closeModal }"/>

                                <lightning:button iconName="utility:send"
                                                  variant="brand" 
                                                  label="Done"
                                                  title="Done"
                                                  onclick="{!c.saveRecord }"/>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

Controller js

```
({
    //@ggalaios 26/03/2020 function on page load
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('doInit.');
        component.set("v.isActionClicked", true);
        console.log('ok done');
        component.set('v.spinner', false);
    },

    //@ggalaios 26/03/2020 function to close modal flow
    closeModal: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.spinner', false);
        component.set('v.isActionClicked', false);
        var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
        if (!recId) {
            var homeEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToObjectHome");
            homeEvt.setParams({
                "scope": "Event"
            });
            homeEvt.fire();
        } else {
            helper.navigateTo(component, recId);
        }
    },


    saveRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('called!');
        component.set("v.eventRecord.Subject", component.find('evtSubject').get("v.value"));
        component.set("v.eventRecord.OwnerId", component.find('evtAssignedTo').get("v.value"));

        component.set("v.eventRecord.StartDateTime", component.find('evtStart').get("v.value"));
        component.set("v.eventRecord.EndDateTime", component.find('evtEnd').get("v.value"));

        console.log('after cmps. set!');


        //Call Apex to get the Questions for the current Page
        var saveEvent = component.get("c.saveEvent");
        saveEvent.setParams({"currentEvent" : component.get('v.eventRecord')});
        saveEvent.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var saveEventState = response.getState();
            if(saveEventState==="SUCCESS"){
                var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                resultsToast.setParams({
                    "title": "Saved",
                    "message": "The record was saved."
                });
                resultsToast.fire();
                var evt = response.getReturnValue();
                var recId = evt.Id;
                helper.navigateTo(component, recId);
            } else if(saveEventState == "INCOMPLETE"){
                component.set("v.spinner", false);
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Oops!",
                    "message": "No Internet Connection",
                    type: "warning",
                    mode: "sticky"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            } else if(saveEventState == "ERROR"){
                component.set("v.spinner", false);
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Error Occured!",
                    "message": "Please contact your Administrator and try again later.",
                    type: "error",
                    mode: "sticky"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();                    
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(saveEvent);
    }
})
```

Helpr Js

```
({
    navigateTo: function(component, recId) {
        var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        navEvt.setParams({
            "recordId": recId
        });
        navEvt.fire();
        window.setTimeout(
            $A.getCallback(function() {
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            }), 2000
        );
    }
})
```

Apex Controller

```
public class PoCEventsManagement {
    public static Event saveEvent (Event currentEvent) {
        //try{
            insert currentEvent;
            return currentEvent;
        /*} catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AurahandledException('Could not save record');
        }*/
    }
}
```

The error i get is This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: -491200357). Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found solution... I called an apex method from init js class to instantiate an event record! Code below

Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:availableForFlowScreens,lightning:actionOverride"
                controller="PoCEventsManagement"
                access="global">

    <!-- Event Handlers -->
    <aura:handler value="{!this}" name="init" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <!--Define Attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="eventRecord" type="Event" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="isActionClicked" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="spinner" type="boolean" default="true"/>

    <!-- If action is selected, show a modal!-->
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isActionClicked}">
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_small">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <!--loading spinner start-->
                <div class="slds-is-relative">
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.spinner}">
                        <div aura:id="spinnerId" class="slds-spinner_container">
                            <div class="slds-spinner--brand  slds-spinner slds-spinner--medium slds-is-relative" role="alert">
                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </aura:if>

                    <!--Loading spinner end--> 
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                              onclick="{! c.closeModal }"
                                              alternativeText="close"
                                              variant="bare-inverse"
                                              class="slds-modal__close"/>
                        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_small slds-hyphenate">New Event</h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_small slds-wrap"  id="modal-content-id-1">
                        <!--26/03/2020 George Galaios: Subject-->
                        <lightning:input aura:id="evtSubject" name="evtSubject" label="Subject" value="{!v.eventRecord.Subject}" required="true" class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small" />

                        <!--26/03/2020 George Galaios: Assigned to-->
                        <lightning:input aura:id="evtAssignedTo" name="evtAssignedTo" label="OwnerId" value="{!v.eventRecord.OwnerId}" required="true" class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small" />

                        <!--26/03/2020 George Galaios: Start Datetime-->
                        <lightning:input aura:id="evtStart" type="Datetime" name="evtStart" label="Start" value="{!v.eventRecord.StartDateTime}" year="2-digit" month="short" day="2-digit" hour="numeric"
                                         weekday="long" minute="2-digit" class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small" />

                        <!--26/03/2020 George Galaios: End Datetime-->
                        <lightning:input aura:id="evtEnd" type="Datetime" name="evtEnd" label="End" value="{!v.eventRecord.EndDateTime}" year="2-digit" month="short" day="2-digit" hour="numeric"
                                         weekday="long" minute="2-digit" class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small" />

                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
                            <div class="slds-p-top_medium"></div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Code for Address Input -->
                        <lightning:inputAddress aura:id="evtAddress" name="evtAddress" addressLabel="Address"
                                                showAddressLookup="True"
                                                streetLabel="Street"
                                                cityLabel="City"
                                                countryLabel="Country"
                                                postalCodeLabel="PostalCode"
                                                street="{!v.eventRecord.Street__c}"
                                                city="{!v.eventRecord.City__c}"
                                                country="{!v.eventRecord.Country__c}"
                                                postalCode="{!v.eventRecord.Postal_Code__c}"
                                                class="slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-horizontal_x-small">
                        </lightning:inputAddress>
                        <!--End of Code for Address Input -->
                    </div>
                    <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <lightning:button iconName="utility:undo"
                                          iconPosition="right"
                                          variant="neutral" 
                                          label="Cancel Flow"
                                          title="Cancel Flow"
                                          onclick="{! c.closeModal }"/>

                                <lightning:button iconName="utility:send"
                                                  variant="brand" 
                                                  label="Done"
                                                  title="Done"
                                                  onclick="{!c.saveRecord }"/>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

Js Controller

```
({
    //@ggalaios 26/03/2020 function on page load
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('doInit.');
        component.set("v.isActionClicked", true);
        console.log('ok done');
        component.set('v.spinner', false);
        //Call Apex to Instantiate a new event
        var createEvent = component.get("c.createNewEvent");
        createEvent.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var createEventState = response.getState();
            if(createEventState==="SUCCESS"){
                var newevt = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.eventRecord", newevt);
                console.log('hey, event record is instantiated!');
            } else if(createEventState == "INCOMPLETE"){
                component.set("v.spinner", false);
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Oops!",
                    "message": "No Internet Connection",
                    type: "warning",
                    mode: "sticky"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            } else if(createEventState == "ERROR"){
                component.set("v.spinner", false);
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Error Occured!",
                    "message": "Please contact your Administrator and try again later.",
                    type: "error",
                    mode: "sticky"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();                    
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(createEvent);
    },

    //@ggalaios 26/03/2020 function to close modal flow
    closeModal: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.spinner', false);
        component.set('v.isActionClicked', false);
        var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
        if (!recId) {
            var homeEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToObjectHome");
            homeEvt.setParams({
                "scope": "Event"
            });
            homeEvt.fire();
        } else {
            helper.navigateTo(component, recId);
        }
    },


    saveRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('called!');
        component.set("v.eventRecord.Subject", component.find('evtSubject').get("v.value"));
        component.set("v.eventRecord.OwnerId", component.find('evtAssignedTo').get("v.value"));

        component.set("v.eventRecord.StartDateTime", component.find('evtStart').get("v.value"));
        component.set("v.eventRecord.EndDateTime", component.find('evtEnd').get("v.value"));
        /*ADDRESS INFORMATION SECTION*/
        component.set("v.eventRecord.ShippingStreet", component.find('evtAddress').get("v.Street__c"));
        component.set("v.eventRecord.ShippingCity", component.find('evtAddress').get("v.City__c"));
        component.set("v.eventRecord.ShippingCountry", component.find('evtAddress').get("v.Country__c"));
        component.set("v.eventRecord.ShippingPostalCode", component.find('evtAddress').get("v.Postal_Code__c"));
        console.log('after cmps. set!');


        //Call Apex to save the Event record
        var saveEvent = component.get("c.saveEvent");
        saveEvent.setParams({"currentEvent" : component.get('v.eventRecord')});
        saveEvent.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var saveEventState = response.getState();
            if(saveEventState==="SUCCESS"){
                var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                resultsToast.setParams({
                    "title": "Saved",
                    "message": "The record was saved."
                });
                resultsToast.fire();
                var evt = response.getReturnValue();
                var recId = evt.Id;
                helper.navigateTo(component, recId);
            } else if(saveEventState == "INCOMPLETE"){
                component.set("v.spinner", false);
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Oops!",
                    "message": "No Internet Connection",
                    type: "warning",
                    mode: "sticky"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            } else if(saveEventState == "ERROR"){
                component.set("v.spinner", false);
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Error Occured!",
                    "message": "Please contact your Administrator and try again later.",
                    type: "error",
                    mode: "sticky"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();                    
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(saveEvent);
    }
})
```

Helper

```
({
    navigateTo: function(component, recId) {
        var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        navEvt.setParams({
            "recordId": recId
        });
        navEvt.fire();
        window.setTimeout(
            $A.getCallback(function() {
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            }), 2000
        );
    }
})
```

Apex Controller

```
public class PoCEventsManagement {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Event saveEvent (Event currentEvent) {
        //try{
            insert currentEvent;
            return currentEvent;
        /*} catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AurahandledException('Could not save record');
        }*/
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Event createNewEvent() {
        Event evt = new Event();
        return evt;
    }
}
```